# Spark deserialization of dataframe struct inside array of struct

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a dataframe schema (for data stored in parquet format) as below

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mid: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- relationship: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- child_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- details: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- package_contains: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- package_level: string (nullable = true)
```

If I have a query like

```
df.select($"id",$"mid").filter(array_contains(col("relationship.child_id"), "id1") && $"mid" === 1).show(false)
```

Does anyone know whether spark deserializes `details` struct inside the array of struct (`relationship`) when querying only for `child_id` column? and if there is a way to verify it?

Answer (score 0):

Spark won't look into the `details` struct unless it is necessary.

I create a new artifical dataset with the same structure. The `details` struct is calculated by an udf. Later, the udf is changed so that it throws an Exception at runtime. If the query still works, I know that the udf has not been called and the `details` struct has not been evaluated.

#### Attempt 1: the "nice" udf

```scala
def details(x:Int): Tuple2[String, String] = ("a", "b")
val detailsUdf = udf(details _)

val df = spark.range(start = 0, end = 5, step = 1)
  .withColumn("mid", lit(1))
  .withColumn("relationship",
      array(struct(concat(lit("id"),'id).as("child_id"), detailsUdf('id).as("details"))))
```

`df` now has the structure

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- mid: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- relationship: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- child_id: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- details: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

and contains the data

```
+---+---+---------------+
| id|mid|   relationship|
+---+---+---------------+
|  0|  1|[[id0, [a, b]]]|
|  1|  1|[[id1, [a, b]]]|
|  2|  1|[[id2, [a, b]]]|
|  3|  1|[[id3, [a, b]]]|
|  4|  1|[[id4, [a, b]]]|
+---+---+---------------+
```

#### Attempt 2: the bad udf

Now the udf is replaced by

```scala
def details(x:Int): Tuple2[String, String] = throw new NullPointerException
val detailsUdf = udf(details _)
```

The structure of the dataframe is still the same, but calling `show` now throws a `NullPointerException`.

If I run the query

```scala
df.select($"id",$"mid").filter(array_contains(col("relationship.child_id"), "id1") && $"mid" === 1).show(false)
```

I get the expected result

```
+---+---+
|id |mid|
+---+---+
|1  |1  |
+---+---+
```

After changing the query so that Spark has to evaluate the `details` struct

```scala
df.select($"id",$"mid").filter(array_contains(col("relationship.details._1"), "id1") && $"mid" === 1).show(false)
```

the query fails and throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is the `details` struct pruned at server level or client level i.e I want to know if the struct is even downloaded?

Comment: when running the filter query, Spark does not evaluate the field. If the field is acutally loaded from a datasource or not would depend on the source. Csv for example does not support loading of partial rows, while parquet or orc does. So it's safe in your case to assume that the data is not loaded